# network address are given...tell whether the two stations are on same n/w or not

Tags: networking, ip, mask, ipv4

Given the network address of 112.44.0.0 and the network mask of 255.255.0.0 .Would the two stations with addresses 112.44.22.19/16 and 112.44.23.2/16 be on the same network ?

Comment: Another copy and paste homework question. [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Given+the+network+address+of+112.44.0.0+and+the+network+mask+of+255.255.0.0+.Would+the+two+stations+with+addresses+112.44.22.19%2F16+and+112.44.23.2%2F16+)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, of course.

All addresses `122.44.x.x` will be in the same network.
Network mask 255.255.0.0 shows that first two numbers are showing number of network and other two numbers are showing number of edge.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are in the same subnet. Just go through the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) page to understand how exactly the IP addresses are resolved. `255.255.0.0` actually expands to `11111111111111110000000000000000` now if you perform a bit wise and operation to any of the IPs `112.44.22.19` or `112.44.23.2` you will find that they give the same Network prefix ie. `112.44.0.0`. What means these two machines are in the same subnet.